# Convert QGIS geometry into Shapely geometry to use orient method defined in Shapely

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, shapely

My idea is to fix the orientation of a polygon, so no matter the orientation it was created, when I run the code, the polygon become clockwise. How is it possible?

I searched and found the shapely library, and [this documentation](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#shapely.geometry.polygon.orient), may help, but I don't know how to implement.

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
features = layer.getFeatures()

for feature in features:
    shapely.geometry.polygon.orient(polygon, sign=1.0) # How to implement?
```

Comment: check this article [Program Talk | shapely.geometry.polygon.orient](https://programtalk.com/python-examples/shapely.geometry.polygon.orient/).

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/q/36474168/4699904

Comment: How do you store your geometry? Shapefiles use clockwise orientation for polygon outer rings. https://www.esri.com/library/whitepapers/pdfs/shapefile.pdf (page 8)

Comment: So the input of orient function is a "shapely polygon", but I have a QgsFeature, how to transform those types, or I may use the shapely to get the features?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from shapely.geometry.polygon import orient
from shapely.wkt import loads

layer = iface.activeLayer()
features = layer.getFeatures()

layer.startEditing()
for feature in features:
    wkt = feature.geometry().asWkt()
    shapely_geom = loads(wkt)

    if shapely_geom.type == 'MultiPolygon':
        shapely_geom = shapely_geom[0]

    oriented_geom = orient(shapely_geom, -1.0)
    new_wkt = oriented_geom.wkt

    new_geom = QgsGeometry.fromWkt(new_wkt)

    layer.changeGeometry(feature.id(), new_geom)

layer.commitChanges()
```

1. Get geometry as WKT.
2. Convert to Shapely geometry using `loads`.
3. Set orientation using `orient`. `-1.0` means clockwise. If the geometry is a MultiPolygon you should get first item using index.
4. Create `QgsGemetry` using `fromWkt` method.

Comment: Thanks ;). But i get this error: from shapely.geometry.polygon import orient
from shapely.wkt import loads

layer = iface.activeLayer()
features = layer.getFeatures()

layer.startEditing()
for feature in features:
    new_geom = QgsGeometry.fromWkt(orient(loads(feature.geometry().asWkt()), -1.0).wkt)
    layer.changeGeometry(feature.id(), new_geom)

layer.commitChanges().
I'm using QGIS 3.8 zanzibar

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.8\apps\Python37\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 9, in <module>
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.8\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\shapely\geometry\polygon.py", line 392, in orient
    ring = polygon.exterior
AttributeError: 'MultiPolygon' object has no attribute 'exterior'

Comment: I added `[0]`. ->  `loads(feature.geometry().asWkt())[0]`

Comment: Still with the same error, i think it has something to do with the comment in line 29 of code number 6. https://programtalk.com/python-examples/shapely.geometry.polygon.orient/

Comment: What do you get using `feature.geometry().asWkt()` for one feature geometry?

Comment: According to the layer properties the geometry is: Polygon (MultiPolygon)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105353/discussion-between-vitorcsm-and-kadir-sahbaz).

Comment: Please consider using the Geo Interface instead of WKT: https://gist.github.com/sgillies/2217756